# Write similar which function

Tags: r, function, parameter-passing

sorry for unclarity

## myfunction should return index of elements in vector satisfy condition

```
myfunction <- function(vector,condition) 
{
  seq_along(vector)[vector == condition]
}
myfunction(vector == condition)
```

Error: object 'conditions' not found

Comment: That correct way to write the function is like this: `myfunction <- function(x) x == 10`.

Comment: How about `myfunction <- which` ?

Comment: Let me add that it is not at all clear what you're trying to accomplish.  It's not surprising that the two answers open with this statement; it's somewhat more surprising that nobody has asked for clarification.  Please, describe what you are actually trying to do.

Comment: what if the condition is an input? not a constant @TejaK

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure exactly what you want your function to perform. Does it need to show which elements in a vector satisfy a condition (which is what `which(vector == 10)` would do)? If that is your intent, can you just do something like:

```
myfunction <- function(vector, condition){
  which(vector == condition)
}
```

In any case, as far as I'm aware, you can't put a test condition in the parameter definitions of your function.